# Tracking touch event without overwriting send event methods in UIWindow and UIApplication

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, touch-event, uievent

I am trying to implement a session management for a new module to a existing code base in which the `main.m`, `Appdelegate` and `UIApplication` files are **bundled in a library** and we have no access to modify it.

I have tried by adding **Gesture recognizer** to `UIWindow` method to track the touch events but the usual button touch events were misbehaving.

Now am planning to subclass `UIView` and overwrite touches began and hit test method and make all my `UIView` class implements this custom `UIView` class.

**Do we have any better approach to track the touch events apart from the above mentioned approaches?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach will be overwriting **send** event of `UIApplication` and `UIWindow` but its not possible in your case.

Try to add `UIGestureRecognizer` to your application shared `UIWindow` then set its delegate and implement below delegate method.

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
     return NO; 
}
```

By returning `NO` will prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch object.
You can add your implementation for tracking touch event inside this method.